# Unable to pass two dimensional array using double pointer as function argument

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to pass a 2D-array to a function using double pointer,however the compiler is giving the following error

```
[Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void print1(int**, int, int)
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void print1(int **arr,int r,int c);

int main()
{
    int a[2][3]={{10,20,30},{40,50,60}};

    int r=2;
    int c=3;
    print1(a,r,c);
}
void print1(int **arr,int r,int c){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            cout<<arr[i*r+j]<<"\t";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to emulate two dimensional array using double pointer.

Answer (score 3):

A multidimensional array is not an array of pointers. `int**` means a pointer to a pointer where as `int (*)[3]` means a pointer to an array of 3 ints. You should change your `print1` definition to this:

`void print1(int (*arr)[3],int r,int c)`

You're also using `arr` wrong inside of the function. It looks like you're trying to use the pointer as an integer pointing to the beginning of the entire memory region. You should either change it to

`cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";`

or change the definition of `print1` to

`void print1(int *arr,int r,int c)`